# Drawing an ellipse in Java. Nothing is showing up

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

I'm trying to get a solid red circle to appear in a JFrame window. The program displays the window, but there is nothing that appears. I'm confused as to why it doesn't do anything. I tried using a debugger but in the later part of the code(the part where the actual ellipse is created) it says no code exists there.
Here is my code:

```
package Materials;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Drawing extends JFrame{
public Drawing(){
    setTitle("Drawing");
    setSize(500, 500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Drawn_Pic pic = new Drawn_Pic();
    add(pic);
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] arguments){
    Drawing frame = new Drawing(); }
}

class Drawn_Pic extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponet(Graphics comp){
        Graphics2D c2D = (Graphics2D) comp;
        c2D.setColor(Color.red);
        c2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        BasicStroke pen = new BasicStroke(); 
        c2D.setStroke(pen);
        Ellipse2D.Double background = new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 450, 450);
        c2D.fill(background);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you add `@Override` before the method, the compiler will tell you when there's a typo like this.

Answer (score 5):

You have a typo, you want to override `paintComponent`, not `paintComponet` .

Answer (score 2):

The function should be paintComponent, not paintComponet.